# Combining two ordered lists into a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to write a function that adds sequence numbers to each item in a list

```
example function(['a', 'b', 7]) output---> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 7)]
```

currently I have

```
def example(el2):
    el1=list(range(len(el2)))
    new=list(map((lambda LL: [el1,LL]),el2))
    return new
```

but it gives me

```
[[[0, 1, 2], 'a'], [[0, 1, 2], 'b'], [[0, 1, 2], 7]]
```

not the desired output

Answer (score 2):

Just use `list` with `enumerate` and supply a `start` argument of `1`:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 7]

res = list(enumerate(L, 1))

[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension`:

```
input_list = ['a', 'b', 7]
output_list = [(i,e) for i, e in enumerate(input_list, start=1)]
```

or using a function:

```
def example(input_list):
    return [(i,e) for i,e in enumerate(input_list, start=1)]

output_list = example(input_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways to do this, a simple way is to iterate over the input list with a counter.  Basically the output is the (item-count, item), so this seems a good way forward.

```
input_list = ['a', 'b', 7 ]

def example(el2):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(el2)):
        output.append((i+1, el2[i]))
    return output

print(str(example(input_list)))
```

I'm not a big fan of lambda functions (in any programming language), as (IMMHO) they make for less-readable code.